# Run `checktime` only if buffer contents are different to the file contents

Tags: save, load

Sometimes a `checktime` causes a prompt to reload, even if the reloading would not change the buffer.

This can be demonstrated (neovim 0.5):

1. Open file in vim1 (terminal 1)
2. Open the same file in vim2 (terminal 2)
3. Change the file in vim2, save it
4. In vim1, run `:checktime`
5. Decline the offer to reload
6. In vim2, undo the change, and save the file
7. In vim1, run `:checktime`
8. `vim` offers to reload the file, even though the buffer contents are identical to what's on disk

The offer to reload seems to go against `:help timestamps`, which says:

> When Vim notices the timestamp of a file has changed, and the file is being
> edited in a buffer but has not changed, Vim checks if the contents of the file
> is equal.  This is done by reading the file again (into a hidden buffer, which
> is immediately deleted again) and comparing the text.  If the text is equal,
> you will get no warning.

A `git rebase` can cause something analogous to the above sequence to occur, causing  [an automated `checktime`](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/27078/5324) to offer to reload a file that's exactly the same as the buffer contents.

I would like to replace the `checktime` call with a function described in pseudocode:

```
if (check_file_timestamps_changed):
    if (buffer_contents != file_contents):
        checktime
    else:
        reset_checktime_counter
```

What `viml` magic functions should I use for the pseudocode:

- `check_file_timestamps_changed`
- `buffer_contents != file_contents`
- `reset_checktime_counter`